# Count total docs containing specific field in Lucene index

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I am trying to run a query on Lucene .NET 2.9.2 index without any luck:

My index holds documents, some of them contain numeric field called "MyNum" and some of them are not.
The field is indexed.

I am trying to count the total documents that contain the field, no matter the fields value.

Could some one please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

A query like **fieldX:*** should return all of the documents that contain field "fieldX".

You may need to allow for a prefixed ***** in your search (I don't have a copy of Lucene up at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the wildcard query to retrieve all documents with specific field. Just provide the * as value (this is just regular wildcard). Here is the sample code:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(new WildcardQuery(new Term("MyNum", "*")), int.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(docs.TotalHits);
```